# Conditionally rendering an object if defined, complains if it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I want to use object only if it is defined, it complains when object is not defined(and is not used). WHy it complains if it is not used? How to solve?

```
const User = (props) =>
  {

const auser=props.user


    return (

<div>
if(auser)
  {    <div><h1>{auser.name}</h1>
    <h2>added blogs</h2>

{auser.blogs.map((it)=>(<div>{it.title}</div>))}
    </div>
}
</div>

    )
```

Comment: Provide more details. Which line is giving the error/warning. What is the error/warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `if` inside a return statement. You should use the `?` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to create an inline if/else statement:

```
return (
  <div>
  auser ? (
    <div><h1>{auser.name}</h1>
      <h2>added blogs</h2>

      {auser.blogs.map((it)=>(<div>{it.title}</div>))}
    </div>
  ) : ""
  </div>
)
```